# API Platform 3 non-identifier path parameters

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

In previous versions of API Platform you've been able to define the path for an operation with route parameters in the standard Symfony style, i.e. /resource/{id}/{parameter}

In the newest version of API Platform (v3) the configuration of these paths seems to have changed so that you need to create a Link() metadata for each parameter which maps a them directly to a property, which is in turn used by doctrine alter the queries dynamically. The issue is that I don't want {parameter} to be LInk-ed at all as it does not directly represent a property.

Is there a way to declare a parameter as a non identifier? Or as a non Link()? If you don't define a uriVariables entry for it then it assumes that it is the id for the mapped entity.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and i resolved it using a fake public property in the entity itself (api-platform 2.7 with the flag to 3), and mapping the {parameter} to that property

> 'id' => 'fake_public_property'

Answer (score 0):

API Platform v3, or v2.7 with the `metadata_backward_compatibility_layer` disabled, enforces stricter adherence to REST conventions and standards.

According to REST standards, only the **resource-id** should be included in the URI as path parameters. As a result, in API Platform v3, there has been a shift in behavior. The platform assumes that any URL parameters should be transformed into entities.

If you wish to prevent automatic retrieval of the entity in a custom operation, you can achieve this by setting the `read` attribute to `false`:

```php
#[ApiResource(operations: [
    new Get(),
    new Post(
        name: 'publication', 
        uriTemplate: '/resource/{id}/{parameter}', 
        controller: CustomActionController::class, 
        read: false,
        write: false
    )
])]
```

The same feature can be applied to POST operations by using the `write` attribute with a value of `false`.

However, it's important to note that this behavior deviates from the standard REST approach. It might be worth considering a refactoring of your approach to align with REST best practices.

For instance, instead of using a structure like:

```
GET /resource/{id}/{parameter}
```

You might want to opt for:

```
GET /resource/{id}?parameter=sometitle
```

You may also be interested about integrating Subresource throught the uriVariables parameter. See  https://api-platform.com/docs/core/subresources/